# Add some custom text to a single file that hooks into Woocommerce email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I am making changes to the WooCommerce email templates and need to add some plain html (about the company's return policy, opening hours, etc.) across a number of files.  I don't want to hard code these into every template but would rather use hooks (if that is the right term?)

If I create a new file called informative-text.php in the same folder as the modified email template files how do I add it in to the admin-new-order.php file?

Comment: Hi Loïc, I have added some more information for you

Comment: would that solution work to add the same text to multiple email templates? if so, would you mind showing me what the function should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead it should be better to set the code of informative-text.php inside a function and then to use any available hook of your convenience. You can use for example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'action_email_customer_details', 30, 4 );
function action_email_customer_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    ?>
    <p>HERE GO YOUR TEXT</p><br>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.